# MikTex issue using ClearSans with XeLatex

Tags: xetex, miktex, fontspec, miktex2.9

I am running into some trouble trying to compile a document using the ClearSans font with XeLaTeX. I am running an up-to-date copy of MikTex, all packages have been updated yesterday. The following is the minimal non-working example I will refer to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with XeLaTeX gives the following errors:

```
D:\test\> xelatex test.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.
sty (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def)
))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.s
ty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def"))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/clearsans\ClearSans.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.def"))
! Undefined control sequence.
\__fontspec_init_ttc:n #1->\str_if_eq:eeT
                                          {\str_lower_case:f {\l__fontspec_e...
l.58       {ClearSans}

?
```

I simply have no idea what is causing this and hope that someone here might be able to tilt me into the right direction. So, the question is:

Why isn't this working / What am I doing wrong?

By the way, this compiles fine with `pdflatex` when the `fontspec` dependency is commented out, but remember the above is just a minimal example, I really do need to get this working for `xelatex`.

Comment: You have an outdated fontspec. Run the update manager always also as user. Only admin is not enough.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that was indeed it, I had to update as user. Feel free to post as an answer =).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is resolved by updating to newest version